# How to derive the Euclidean norm of a matrix from its spectral radius

Tags: matrices, spectral-radius

For a matrix $A\in R^{n \times n}$, if there is a positive $\rho \in (0,1)$ s.t. $\rho(A) \leq \rho$, where $\rho(A)$ represents the spectral radius of $A$.

Can we get the following conclusions:$\Vert A \Vert_2 \leq \rho$ ?

For example, let
\begin{equation}
A=\left[
\begin{array}
 &1-3w& h &1 \\
-3w^2 &1 &h\\
-w^3& 0& 1
\end{array}
\right].
\end{equation}
Let $hw \in (0,1)$, it is obvioulys that the spectral radius of $A$ is $1-hw$. If there is a positive $\rho \in (0,1)$ s.t. $1-hw \leq \rho$, can we obtain a upper bound less than 1 of  $\Vert A \Vert_2$ ?

Comment: certainly no: check nilpotent matrices

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement is known as Householder Theorem: For every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a norm $\|\cdot\|$ over ${\mathbb C}^n$, such that the subordinated norm of $A$ is $\le\rho(A)+\epsilon$.

As mentionned by Fedor, the result is false with $\epsilon=0$ because if $A\ne0_n$ is nilpotent, then $\rho(A)=0$ and $\|A\|=0$ for every norm.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I'm only interested in its 2 norm and a bound less than 1.  There are some additions in the title  to illustrate my question.

Comment: @DOUSHIMAFAN If you change the rules in the middle of the game, how can we give you a relevant answer ?